# Laravel: How to update pivot tables withou using first

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, pivot, pivot-table

Im new in Laravel. I want to update my leaves pivot table. I am trying with below code but it only updates the single row i have multiple rows in db with same leave_id and i want to update all this where leave_id = xyz

I have following function in my model Leave:

```
public function relLeave(){

    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class)->withPivot('days');

}
```

LeaveController:

```
public function saveUpdate(Request $request)
{
  $leave = Leave::find($request->id);
  $msg = $leave->relLeave()->Where('leave_id', $request->id)->get()->first();
 $msg->pivot->days = $request->days;
 $msg->pivot->save();
}
```

Comment: It'll only update the first as you're running `->get()->first();` try changing this to just `->get();` then `dd($msg)` to ensure it fetches correctly. If it does run a simple foreach loop..

Answer (score 1):

I followed @option's instruction and it works for me i removed the first();

below is my updated code.

```
     $msg = $leave->relLeave()->Where('leave_id', $request->id)->get();
        foreach($msg as $msgs)
        {
            $msgs->pivot->days = $request->days;
            $msgs->pivot->save();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can update extra fields in pivot table when updating relationship

```
$leave->relLeave()->sync([$request['id'] => ['days' => $request['days']]]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Query Builder for that if it's an option:

```
DB::table('leave_user')->where('leave_id', $request->id)->update(['days' => $request->days]);
```

This is just one DB query and it's pretty simple one.

If you want Eloquent solution, use [`updateExistingPivot()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships) in a loop:

```
$leave = Leave::find($request->id);
$usersIds = $leave->relLeave()->pluck('id')->toArray();
foreach ($usersIds as $userId) {
     $leave->relLeave()->updateExistingPivot($userId, ['days' => $request->days]);
}
```